# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'system_channel'

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a command where the bot sends me an invite of a server by `,dm (server id)` and this is what I made so far:

```
@client.command(name='dm')
async def dm(ctx, guild_id: int):
    if ctx.author.id == owner:
        guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
        guildchannel = guild.system_channel
        invitelink = await guildchannel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
        await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```

Some servers work and some don't. The ones that don't work sends this: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_invite'` and sometimes it sends me 2 invite links of the same server. Please help as soon as possible and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your bot a member of those guilds? Have you tried [`fetch_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_guild)?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh fetch_guild doesn't work either, it gives me the same error message

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your `client.get_guild(guild_id)` is returning None, this means your bot either isn't in the guild or your `guild_id` isn't a valid guild ID</s>

UPDATE:
On second thought I think your target server does not have a `system_channel`.  You can check then in your Guild Settings > Overview > System Messages Channel.

Comment: I don't think its that problem because I have a command that sends me a list of guilds that the bot is in and the guild ID's too.

Comment: Does this guild have a  `system_channel`? Your error is on, `guildchannel.create_invite`, now that I look you are probably getting a guild object but it might not have a `system_channel`

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to change this, here is the code:

```
@client.command(name='dm')
async def _dm(ctx, guild_id: int):
    if ctx.author.id == owner:
        guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
        channel = guild.channels[-1]
        invitelink = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=1)
        await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```